# object class in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to know the what are the methods and properties in the `object` class of Python but I can't find the documentation anywhere. Do you guys know where can I find it?

Comment: You can also use `ipython` with its awesome tab completion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=object#dir) to list them:

```
>>> dir(object)
['__class__',
 '__delattr__',
 '__dir__',
 '__doc__',
 '__eq__',
 '__format__',
 '__ge__',
 '__getattribute__',
 '__gt__',
 '__hash__',
 '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__',
 '__le__',
 '__lt__',
 '__ne__',
 '__new__',
 '__reduce__',
 '__reduce_ex__',
 '__repr__',
 '__setattr__',
 '__sizeof__',
 '__str__',
 '__subclasshook__']
```

Be warned that an object can lie about what attributes are there.  For example, `object.mro` exists but the dir chooses not to tell you about it.

To find an "uncensored" list, try this:

```
>>> object.__dir__(object)
```

Comment: `dir()` doesn't show methods provided by `type`, the metaclass of `object`. `object.mro` is really `type.mro`.

Comment: As for `object.__dir__()` vs. `dir()`, the latter calls `type.__dir__(object)`, while `object.__dir__()` is meant for *instances* (so used for `dir(instance)`). The latter also looks at `type(instance)`, while the former does not, which is why the `object.__dir__(object)` list is larger. You basically have the same output as `list(set(dir(object)).union(dir(type)))` (modulus ordering).

Comment: As documented in the link provided.  *Note Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.*