# Are all attributes in dir(object) accessible in Python?

Tags: python, oop

I just did `dir(type)` and it listed a lot of things:

```
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__', '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']

>>> type.__base__
<class 'object'>

>>> type.__abstractmethods__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: __abstractmethods__
```

Can some help me understand why this behavior? I was just trying to understand Python's attribute lookup and why it doesn't always check with its `Parent`. It seems like it doesn't do that always, but I need to understand why doesn't a `Child` not have a `Parent's` "behaviour" :-). I thought that is how it works, it looks like I need to explore more.

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Short answer: no. Some attributes are in dir, but not accessible. Some are not in dir, but are accessible

Comment: All of them are accessible, but some are descriptors that don't do anything normally.

Comment: `dir` is designed to help you debug. Human readable if you prefer.

Comment: There's also some relevant info in Martijn's comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45426018/object-class-in-python-3/45426113#comment77825217_45426113).